# VS 2015 RC: Git integration crashed

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio

Suddenly, Visual Studio started showing this error at startup: "SccProviderPackage failed to load".

Also, the Team Explorer window stopped showing the proper section for Git.

**I've repaired the installation, uninstalled/installed VS and restarted several times. NOTHING fixes the issue.**

Please, notice that it's Visual Studio 2015 RC.

The activity log (ActivityLog.xml) says this:

- 174  Begin package load [**SccProviderPackage**] {7FE30A77-37F9-4CF2-83DD-96B207028E1B}  VisualStudio 2015/06/15 09:31:26.510
- 175 **ERROR** **SetSite** failed for package [**SccProviderPackage**] {7FE30A77-37F9-4CF2-83DD-96B207028E1B} 80131500 VisualStudio 2015/06/15 09:31:26.556
- 176 **ERROR** End package load [**SccProviderPackage**] {7FE30A77-37F9-4CF2-83DD-96B207028E1B} 80131500 VisualStudio 2015/06/15 09:31:26.561

The Team Explorer window shows this:

[image: Team Explorer]

---

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.ServiceProviderExtensionMethods.EnsurePackageLoaded(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Guid packageGuid)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.ServiceProviderExtensionMethods.EnsureSccAndTfPackagesLoaded(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.Repositories.GitTeamProjectExtendedInfoProvider.set_ServiceProvider(IServiceProvider
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.ConnectPage.ConnectPageVS.Initialize(Object
>   sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext
>   context)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this same issue, look in your [Appdata]\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml for references to SccProviderPackage.  Should give you the error info.

In my case it was trying to load an old folder location that apparently had a messed up repo.  Removing that folder from the filesystem fixed it.

Running this command makes sure that all activity is logged:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>Devenv /log
```